# Pose mirroring being glitchy

Tags: animation, mirror, fcurves

I'm learning to animate a creature I recently created and I need your help. I know that it's possible to mirror poses by naming the bones of the armature correctly using the following naming system: **example.L and example.R**

I've named my bones so the mirror pose action would work properly. The body of the creature is also done by using the mirror modifier (so it should be symmetrical along the y-axis). In addition, the weight paint of the bones is also mirrored. Here's also a picture of my named bones - right leg in green and left leg in purple:

[image]

Here's also a mirror animation I've been trying to do.. Purple bones show the mirror effect.. 
The left leg is 30 frames behind the right leg so one leg is on the floor at a time. 
[image]

EDIT: Added one more problem associated with the glitchy pose mirroring.

I have an IK target that somehow won't mirror the Y-axis location. I don' t understand what may cause it. There's no lock icon next to the y-axis location parameter which is strange. Here's a picture to visualize the problem:

[image]

Here's a picture of a graph - the green line shows the y-axis location frame by frame. It shouldn't be constantly linear as you can see the movement of the other leg.
[image]

The leg animation.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how you mirrored the pose? What were the steps you took?

Comment: I selected the right leg, pressed the copy pose button (or used CTRL + C keyboard shortcut), moved 30 frames ahead (because the left leg should have the same pose after 30 frames) and pressed the mirror pose button (or used CTRL + SHIFT + V keyboard shortcut).

Comment: It should have worked. Try recalculating the bone roll for the top purple bone and the one below it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by recalculating the bone roll?
Do you mean I should clear the pose? If so, then I've done this about three times already and tried to mirror the poses again, but apparently it doesn' t solve the problem..

Comment: Could the problem be somehow associated with the fact that I haven' t applied rotation nor position for my model nor the armature?

Comment: Select your bones, go into the Pose menu, and you'll see an option for recalculating the bone roll. I can see that the top two bones are out of line by the way they twist. That's sometimes caused by a misplaced bone roll. You can see what the bone roll value is in the properties panel of the 3d viewer when the bone is selected. You can also change it from there. Make sure the bone rolls are mirrored values of the other leg.I.e. if the good leg bone is at -45 degreees, try changing the other leg bone to 45 degrees.

Comment: Thanks. It partly solved my problem. The upper part of the leg won't twist anymore. But there's another problem I didn' t mention earlier. I edited my question to show the problem (can add some pictures there)

Comment: I don't know what the problem is. I would post it as a new question to get better help.

Comment: Okay. I'll do it :)
Thanks for helping me out with the bone roll problem though :)